# What is the meaning of colors in activation maps?

Tags: deep-learning, keras, visualization, activation-function

I am trying to understand how the neural network works. I plotted the intermediate layer activations and I got the following image.

[image]

I used the matplotlib library and selected `cmap='jet'`. I would like to know what is the meaning of these colors? Does the area with color red mean the filter is activated in that region? Then, what about the green, yellow and blue color means?

Comment: What is the shape of the array/tensor you passed to matplotlib?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a heat map, where "hotter" means "higher values". They are very useful for studying CNNs, since they let you see what each convolutional filters *see* in each image.

Some filters are activated with vertical lines, other with diagonal or with round shapes... the deeper you go into the network, the more complex are the things each layer is looking for. Heatmaps of activations let you do that.

Answer (score 1):

In heat maps, generally reddish regions represents higher values where as bluish ones represent lower.

Comment: @Ali Raza Memom Do you have any doubts?

Comment: thanks for the clarification